# Simple jQuery Script Not Working FadeIn/FadeOut Based on Scroll Height (Does on jsfiddle)

Tags: jquery, scroll, fadein, fadeout

http://jsfiddle.net/MFUw3/678/ This is working on jsFiddle the only issue is the script doesn't take effect until scrolling back and forth.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(window).scroll(function() { 
   if($(window).scrollTop()>0) {
     $('.small-logo').fadeOut();
      } else {
     $('.small-logo').fadeIn();
  }
});  
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't take effect until scrolling back and forth because on load, `.scrollTop()` is equal to 0. What behaviour are you trying to achieve on load?

Comment: the small logo is not to show until it passes the big logo, the class for the big logo is .large-logo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are using `jQuery.noConflict()` then you try to use `$`
- The code uses `scrollHeight()` instead of `scrollTop()`

Here it is how it should look your code:

```
(function($){
    var $window = $(window);

    $window.scroll(function(){
        if ($window.scrollTop() >= 162) {
            $('.small-logo').fadeOut();
        }
        else {
            $('.small-logo').fadeIn();
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

This is your current code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 
  if($(window).scrollHeight()>=162) {
   $('.small-logo').fadeOut();
  } else {
   $('.small-logo').fadeIn();
}
});
```

Comment: Maybe also make it id's? Will save alot of resource, every pixel scrolled fires this function, and jQuery+#ID is the way to go if performace matters

Comment: Oh the small-logo should not show, after refreshing it is there. It should only appear after scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you trying to do : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/MFUw3/685/)

```
.a {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 50%;
    display:none;
}
```